How to prevent click gesture on screen when Popup is shown?
When TooltipBox is open clicking any Composable on screen has no effect other than dismissing Popup. How does it do it and what's effective way to implement it no matter where current Composable is in Composition tree when a Popup is open so no other Composable out of Popup receives any gestures.

@Preview
@Composable
fun TooltipBoxSample() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
    ) {
        Button(
            onClick = {}
        ){
            Text("Some button")
        }

        val state = rememberTooltipState(
            isPersistent = true
        )
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(120.dp))

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
        ) {
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp))

            TooltipBox(
                positionProvider = rememberPlainTooltipPositionProvider(
                    spacingBetweenTooltipAndAnchor = 16.dp
                ),
                state = state,
                tooltip = {

                    PlainTooltip(
                        caretProperties = CaretProperties(
                            caretWidth = 16.dp,
                            caretHeight = 16.dp
                        ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(16.dp),
                        containerColor = Color.Red
                    ) {
                        Text(
                            text = "Tooltip Content for testing...",
                            modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp)
                        )
                    }

                },
                content = {
                    Icon(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .size(60.dp)
                            .clickable {
                                coroutineScope.launch {
                                    state.show()
                                }
                            },
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.Info,
                        contentDescription = null
                    )
                }
            )
        }

    }
}

If you touch anywhere on screen with Popup Composables receive click events

@Preview
@Composable
fun PopupOpenCloseTest() {

    var showPopup by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }


    Column(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
    ) {

        Button(
            onClick = {}
        ) {
            Text("Some button")
        }

        Box {
            Icon(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .border(2.dp, Color.Blue)
                    .size(60.dp)
                    .clickable {
                        if (showPopup.not()) {
                            showPopup = true
                        }
                        println("CLICKED showPopup: $showPopup")
                    },
                imageVector = Icons.Default.Info,
                contentDescription = null
            )

            if (showPopup) {
                Popup(
                    offset = IntOffset(300, 300),
                    onDismissRequest = {
                        if (showPopup) {
                            showPopup = false
                        }
                    }
                ) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White).padding(16.dp)
                    ) {
                        Text("Popup Content")
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }
}

I inspected source code of Tooltip and BasicTooltip but there is no place it creates a Window or View that cancels gesture, or consume any.

Making the Popup focusable will do the trick:
Popup(
  properties = PopupProperties(focusable = true),
  ...
)


Good catch. I figured this one out one hour after asking the question but i thought someone else answering would be more appropriate, i was gonna answer if anyone didn't in 24 hours. TooltipBox does nothing other than setting focusable true by the way
